# Matlab Imread resizes tif file

Tags: matlab

so I'm using the imread function in matlab and when I save the TIFF file and open it in photoshop, it has a white border and I can't understand why. I want to maintain its resolution as a 512 by 512 image. Any ideas why? And how I can fix that?

Here's a sample code:

```
B = imread('W_noise1.tif');

for n = 1:5,
    B = medfilt2(B);
end

B = filter2(fspecial('average',3),B)/255;

imshow(B)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it's an issue with imread?  I'd be surprised if it is.

See [this link about medfilt2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/medfilt2.html) where it explains that "medfilt2 pads the image with 0s on the edges, so the median values for the points within [m n]/2 of the edges might appear distorted."

EDIT:  I tried to replicate your problem.  This is an issue with `print` where it puts a white frame around the image after you save it.  This functionality, `print` is made for printing plots.  If you want to save the image, you should use `imwrite`.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm unsure of. I use imshow(I) to display the image and when I save the image and reopen it, the resolution is changed. It doesn't maintain the 512x512 image that was read in. I always have that white border there, so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Are you talking about imshow on the original image, or imshow on the image after the medfilt2.  My point is to take medfilt2 out of the equation to see what's going on.

Comment: Edit (see above) this is an issue with `print`.